# SpringSecurity custom AuthProvider

Tags: spring-security, single-sign-on

Suppose I have a Custom Authentication Provider as follows:

```
@Component
public class AuthProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

  @Override
  public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
    // do some and return proper value
    return null; 
  }

  @Override
  public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

For some reasons this is a kind of custom `SSO` who retrieve data from jar installed on the customer server..

Therefore the login call is not a `POST` and don't contain `Authorization` header or something else..

How can I configure my securityConfig class to intercept certain call and start my AuthenticationProvider flow??

For example:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  @Autowired
  AuthProvider authProvider;

  @Override
  protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.authenticationProvider(authProvider);
  }

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
     // how can I say to httpsecurity that when "/ssoauth/**" path is fired it should start the authentication flow?
  }
```

---------------- UPDATE ------------------

the trace log follow:

```
2021-12-02 19:25:35.950 TRACE 8528 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Trying to match request against DefaultSecurityFilterChain [RequestMatcher=any request, Filters=[org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@34b9eb03, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@4d266391, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@7f37b6d9, org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter@5d97caa4, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@4397a639, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@3b5c665c, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@2e5b7fba, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@43fda8d9, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@c29fe36, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@1b495d4, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter@46a488c2]] (1/1)
2021-12-02 19:25:35.951 DEBUG 8528 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /ssoauth/
2021-12-02 19:25:35.954 TRACE 8528 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter (1/11)
2021-12-02 19:25:35.959 TRACE 8528 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking SecurityContextPersistenceFilter (2/11)
2021-12-02 19:25:35.961 TRACE 8528 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : No HttpSession currently exists
2021-12-02 19:25:35.961 TRACE 8528 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Created SecurityContextImpl [Null authentication]
2021-12-02 19:25:35.968 DEBUG 8528 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Set SecurityContextHolder to empty SecurityContext
2021-12-02 19:25:35.969 TRACE 8528 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking HeaderWriterFilter (3/11)
2021-12-02 19:25:35.972 TRACE 8528 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking CsrfFilter (4/11)
2021-12-02 19:25:35.976 TRACE 8528 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter         : Did not protect against CSRF since request did not match CsrfNotRequired [TRACE, HEAD, GET, OPTIONS]
2021-12-02 19:25:35.976 TRACE 8528 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking LogoutFilter (5/11)
2021-12-02 19:25:35.977 TRACE 8528 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.w.a.logout.LogoutFilter            : Did not match request to Ant [pattern='/logout', POST]
2021-12-02 19:25:35.977 TRACE 8528 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking RequestCacheAwareFilter (6/11)
2021-12-02 19:25:35.977 TRACE 8528 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache        : No saved request
2021-12-02 19:25:35.977 TRACE 8528 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter (7/11)
2021-12-02 19:25:35.980 TRACE 8528 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking AnonymousAuthenticationFilter (8/11)
2021-12-02 19:25:35.983 TRACE 8528 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to AnonymousAuthenticationToken [Principal=anonymousUser, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=null], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_ANONYMOUS]]
2021-12-02 19:25:35.984 TRACE 8528 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking SessionManagementFilter (9/11)
2021-12-02 19:25:35.985 DEBUG 8528 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.w.session.SessionManagementFilter  : Request requested invalid session id 6CE9481A4D785D4B71265C70785892D7
2021-12-02 19:25:35.985 TRACE 8528 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking ExceptionTranslationFilter (10/11)
2021-12-02 19:25:35.985 TRACE 8528 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking AuthorizationFilter (11/11)
2021-12-02 19:25:35.988 TRACE 8528 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] estMatcherDelegatingAuthorizationManager : Authorizing SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper[ org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter$HeaderWriterRequest@74c9f7ce]
2021-12-02 19:25:35.990 TRACE 8528 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] estMatcherDelegatingAuthorizationManager : Checking authorization on SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper[ org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter$HeaderWriterRequest@74c9f7ce] using org.springframework.security.authorization.AuthenticatedAuthorizationManager@1c20fe7b
2021-12-02 19:25:36.000 TRACE 8528 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Sending AnonymousAuthenticationToken [Principal=anonymousUser, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=null], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_ANONYMOUS]] to authentication entry point since access is denied

org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access Denied
    at org.springframework.security.authorization.AuthorizationManager.verify(AuthorizationManager.java:44) ~[spring-security-core-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter.doFilterInternal(AuthorizationFilter.java:57) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) [spring-security-web-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:121) [spring-security-web-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:115) [spring-security-web-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) [spring-security-web-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:126) [spring-security-web-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:81) [spring-security-web-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) [spring-security-web-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:105) [spring-security-web-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) [spring-security-web-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:149) [spring-security-web-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) [spring-security-web-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) [spring-security-web-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) [spring-security-web-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:103) [spring-security-web-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:89) [spring-security-web-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) [spring-security-web-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:117) [spring-security-web-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) [spring-security-web-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90) [spring-security-web-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75) [spring-security-web-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) [spring-security-web-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:110) [spring-security-web-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:80) [spring-security-web-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) [spring-security-web-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:55) [spring-security-web-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) [spring-security-web-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:211) [spring-security-web-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:183) [spring-security-web-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358) [spring-web-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271) [spring-web-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) [spring-web-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) [spring-web-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) [spring-web-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:540) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:895) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1722) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_271]

2021-12-02 19:25:36.030 DEBUG 8528 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache        : Saved request http://localhost:8080/ssoauth/ to session
2021-12-02 19:25:36.032 DEBUG 8528 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.w.a.Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint     : Pre-authenticated entry point called. Rejecting access
2021-12-02 19:25:36.033 TRACE 8528 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.w.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter  : Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match request to [Is Secure]
2021-12-02 19:25:36.034 DEBUG 8528 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Did not store empty SecurityContext
2021-12-02 19:25:36.037 DEBUG 8528 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Did not store empty SecurityContext
2021-12-02 19:25:36.037 DEBUG 8528 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Cleared SecurityContextHolder to complete request
2021-12-02 19:25:36.043 TRACE 8528 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Trying to match request against DefaultSecurityFilterChain [RequestMatcher=any request, Filters=[org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@34b9eb03, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@4d266391, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@7f37b6d9, org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter@5d97caa4, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@4397a639, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@3b5c665c, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@2e5b7fba, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@43fda8d9, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@c29fe36, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@1b495d4, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter@46a488c2]] (1/1)
2021-12-02 19:25:36.043 DEBUG 8528 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /error
2021-12-02 19:25:36.043 TRACE 8528 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter (1/11)
2021-12-02 19:25:36.043 TRACE 8528 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking SecurityContextPersistenceFilter (2/11)
2021-12-02 19:25:36.044 TRACE 8528 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Did not find SecurityContext in HttpSession EBC739EB9A31253EEDAC53E01E83F84D using the SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT session attribute
2021-12-02 19:25:36.044 TRACE 8528 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Created SecurityContextImpl [Null authentication]
2021-12-02 19:25:36.044 DEBUG 8528 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Set SecurityContextHolder to empty SecurityContext
2021-12-02 19:25:36.044 TRACE 8528 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking HeaderWriterFilter (3/11)
2021-12-02 19:25:36.044 TRACE 8528 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking CsrfFilter (4/11)
2021-12-02 19:25:36.045 TRACE 8528 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking LogoutFilter (5/11)
2021-12-02 19:25:36.045 TRACE 8528 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.w.a.logout.LogoutFilter            : Did not match request to Ant [pattern='/logout', POST]
2021-12-02 19:25:36.045 TRACE 8528 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking RequestCacheAwareFilter (6/11)
2021-12-02 19:25:36.045 TRACE 8528 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache        : Did not match request /error to the saved one DefaultSavedRequest [http://localhost:8080/ssoauth/]
2021-12-02 19:25:36.045 TRACE 8528 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter (7/11)
2021-12-02 19:25:36.046 TRACE 8528 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking AnonymousAuthenticationFilter (8/11)
2021-12-02 19:25:36.046 TRACE 8528 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to AnonymousAuthenticationToken [Principal=anonymousUser, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=EBC739EB9A31253EEDAC53E01E83F84D], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_ANONYMOUS]]
2021-12-02 19:25:36.046 TRACE 8528 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking SessionManagementFilter (9/11)
2021-12-02 19:25:36.046 TRACE 8528 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking ExceptionTranslationFilter (10/11)
2021-12-02 19:25:36.046 TRACE 8528 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking AuthorizationFilter (11/11)
2021-12-02 19:25:36.047 DEBUG 8528 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Secured GET /error
2021-12-02 19:25:36.295 DEBUG 8528 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Did not store anonymous SecurityContext
2021-12-02 19:25:36.306 DEBUG 8528 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Did not store anonymous SecurityContext
2021-12-02 19:25:36.306 DEBUG 8528 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Cleared SecurityContextHolder to complete request
```

Anyway I would like to remember that is a demo SpringStarterProject with springboot.. I have just those 3 classes

Answer (score 0):

When you configure it like this:

```java
@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.authenticationProvider(authProvider);
}
```

You are adding your `AuthProvider` to the list of `AuthenticationProvider`s that the `ProviderManager` implementation will invoke in order to authenticate the user.

```java
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
     // how can I say to httpsecurity that when "/ssoauth/**" path is fired it should start the authentication flow?
    http.authorizeHttpRequests((requests) -> requests
        .antMatchers("/ssoauth/**").authenticated()
    );
}
```

This way above, you are telling that any requests to `/ssoauth/**` requires authentication, therefore invoking the authentication filters, which uses the `ProviderManager`.

You can have more details in the reference documentation about [Servlet Authentication Architecture](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authentication/architecture.html#servlet-authentication-authenticationmanager).

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. Is the first thing I try but doesn't work.. it respond me forbidden! Same result with browser or postman.

Comment: Add `logging.level.org.springframework.security=TRACE` to your `application.properties` and paste the logs in the question